# how to add if instruction before an if instruction by bcel

Tags: java, if-statement, position, bytecode, bcel

I want to use [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) to add/insert some if_instruction before a specific if_instruction which is in my method.

Here is my method:

```
public void printMax(int x , int y){
  int max=x;
  //////here is my desire position//////////
  if(y>x)
    max=y;
  System.out.println(max);
}
```

Comment: To me the `if(x<y != y>x)` is the same as `if(false)`

Comment: Several comments - check my edit and see how I formatted your code; what you had before was very strange. Second - please don't put two questions in one post. I've removed the second question. Finally, can you explain what you've tried before you posted?

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon: It's the same as `if (x == y)` (for integers)...

Answer (score 0):

To me the `if(x<y != y>x)` is the same as `if(false)` so it would not succeed; so maybe you should use `IF_ACMPNE`, but I don't know BCEL ...

Comment: I appreciate for your help, yes I've made a mistake the correct instruction is

Comment: I appreciate for your help, yes I've made a mistake the correct instruction is 'if(y>x != y<x)' and about bcel, is a library which it can manipulate byte codes http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/